# React reach router link tag updates url but not the component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my **App.js**, I have:

```
<Profile path="/profile/:id" userId={this.state.userId} />
```

In my header/navbar, I have:

```
{this.props.userId ? (
          <Link to={`/profile/${this.props.userId}`} style={link_style}>
            <button className="btn">
              <span>Profile</span>
            </button>
          </Link>
        ) : null}
```

I have my site set up so that you can look at other people's profile. The problem arises here, if you are viewing someone else's profile (say the we are at the link `localhost5000/profile/28937482394` and then you click on your own profile, the link updates to `localhost5000/profile/1021231209` (my profile), but my profile is not displayed -- component not rendered).

Comment: Tough to troubleshoot this without a reproducible example. Any chance you could load a minimal version of your app into codesandbox.io?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because you are trying to implement the nested routes.
I have ever met such issue long before, and I reference the following links, and solved the issue.

https://medium.com/swlh/defining-nested-routes-with-react-router-8f140e87b360
https://reactrouter.com/web/example/nesting

Answer (score 0):

Your **navbar** should be inside **< Router>** and export your **navbar** with **withRouter**

```
  <Router history={history}>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes />
  </Router>,  

  export default withRouter(navbar);
```